# object cannot be resolved in finally block

Tags: finally

Why do I get the error:
***rawData cannot be resoled*** in the finally block?

in:

```
    public void parseData(String fileName) throws IOException
{
    try
    {
        DataInputStream rawData = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));
        /* here I'm gonna do something*/

    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        rawData.close();
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Do or do not; there is no `try`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared `rawData` inside the `try` block.
The variable does not exist outside of it.
In particular, what would happen if the `try` block exits before that line?

You need to move the declaration outside the `try`.

Answer (score 0):

`rawData` is not visible to the `finally` block because it was declared in the `try` block.

```
public void parseData(String fileName) throws IOException
{
    DataInputStream rawData = null;
    try
    {
        rawData = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));
        /* here I'm gonna do something */

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally
    {
        if (rawData != null)
        {
            rawData.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

u should declare rawData outside try/catch/finaly block

```
public void parseData(String fileName) throws IOException
{
    DataInputStream rawData;
    try
    {
        rawData = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));
        /* here I'm gonna do something*/

    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        rawData.close();
    }
}
```